How do I manage the Deck of Many Things?
I'm considering adding a Deck of Many Things to my campaign.
How would I balance this? Is there a way to stop it from upending my entire campaign? How do I keep the story on track?
How do I manage the guaranteed chaos?

https://www.penny-arcade.com/comic/2010/06/28/the-sound-of-a-klaxon

@DougWarren Haha, I saw that webcomic on another question here recently... small Q&A site ;)

While not an answer to this question, my answer to this other question does analyse how disruptive each card in the 5e Deck of Things can potentially be: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/205466/deck-of-many-things-how-problematic-is-each-card-for-a-campaign
That information might be useful to your planning.

Don't give the party control over the Deck, offer them an opportunity to draw a card from it instead
This is how I did it when I wanted to let my players have some fun with the Deck but not have it derail the campaign and it worked very well. Instead of just dropping the Deck into the party's lap for them to do what they want whenever they want with it, you provide a single opportunity for them to interact with it. Have them encounter a powerful NPC who possesses the Deck and offers to let them draw cards, if they try and snatch it from them, the NPC simply teleports away, optionally knocking out everyone first. Have the NPC restrict the number of cards they are allowed to draw if you want to control the interaction further (the way I did it, the offer was a single card for each PC).
This way the Deck appears on your terms, at the point when it's convenient for you to let your players use it and when you know you can handle the results, your players get to use it but they don't get to keep it and continue to draw cards from it at random points throughout the campaign.
If there are some cards that you especially wouldn't want your players to draw, you can remove them in advance - one can still use the Deck even if it's incomplete. The Book of Many Things provides a lot of advice on how to customise the Deck, including options like making it have mostly positive / negative consequences, adjusting it for a low-level party and so on.

+1 my old DM did this and it worked very well. :)

The birth of the Deck of One Pre-selected Thing per Player.

@MindwinRememberMonica I never said anything about it being preselected?

@AnnaAG: There's no rule in the DMG that the DM isn't allowed to use sleight of hand (or whatever method) to stack the deck. It's equivalent to fudging a dice roll. Some tables would hate the idea, others would consider it entirely unremarkable or even praise the DM's forward thinking.

Don’t
If you aren’t ready to embrace chaos, don’t invite it inside for a nightcap.
The Deck of Many Things is perfect for a DM and a group who are perfectly happy to upend their entire campaign on the turn of the card.  If you aren’t willing to do that WTF are you doing in the high-rollers part of the casino?
I’m reminded of a story about Kerry Packer:

It involves a Texan who approached Packer at the tables in Vegas and started making a nuisance of himself.
When asked to give it a rest, the Texan supposedly replied with the old, "Do you know who I am", to which the Packer reply was, "No".
"I happen to be worth $100 million," said the Texan.
"Toss you for it," said Packer. Allegedly.

The deck could be the best or worst thing to happen to your campaign. Either way, you’ll have one hell of a story.


Is there a way to stop it from upending my entire campaign?

No.
Cards run the gamut from "here's a free castle" to "you are dead, your soul is gone, you cannot come back." It's an agent of pure chaos and you're asking how to keep the chaos to a minimum.
If you're not prepared for a player to pull a card that essentially reads "the campaign as you knew it is now over, hope you didn't spend much time planning," but you still really want to use the deck, I'd highly advise going through the many, many different homebrew Decks out there that don't contain so many catastrophic options.

"It's a Trap" — Admiral Ackbar, the battle of Endor.

Stacking the deck
The Book of Many things gives in-depth guidance and ideas in how to use the deck.
It also explains that it is a tool for the DM, and is up to the DM to pre-determine the order in which you will draw cards "randomly", as long as it fits to their vision for the campaign, and says, addressing the DM:

You can ensure certain outcomes by stacking the deck with cards placed in a specific order.

So, there only is guaranteed chaos, if you want it to. If you rather would like to keep your story on track, you can just stack the deck so the cards drawn will not throw the story off, or at least, you can be prepared for the ways they will throw it off.
It's however not your story, if you think about it, it's the joint story of you and the players, and the interesting impulses random effects throw in, from lucky critical hits to failed saving throws to fringe random encounters. The deck just amps the volume up on this last aspect. You can lean into it, or try to minimize it — or, if even that is too much for your tastes, just not use the deck, or limit access to it as in @AnnaAG's answer. I think if you do use the deck, a bit of chaos is part of the fun and excitement.
