# How can I realize my gravity monkey concept?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, druid, monk

I'm about to start a *D&D 3.5* campaign with a generous DM. PCs will start somewhere between levels 5 and 8—the DM hasn't said exactly—with 100,000 gp. I've been working on a build that's like Sun Wukong—the [Monkey King](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_King)—at early levels and [Pain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagato_(Naruto)) from *Naruto*—with all that almighty push stuff—at late levels. My goal is a "gravity monkey" with a mantra of "Strength lies in the sky and in the earth and in the the forces that bind them."

The DM approved of my plan to use the homebrew race [**wukong**](https://dnd-wiki.org/wiki/Wukong_(3.5e_Race)).

I'm planning on 2 levels of monk unless a better option presents itself then levels of druid then ending up at level 20 having 6–10 levels of the homebrew prestige class [**mage of the unseen force**](https://dnd-wiki.org/wiki/Mage_of_the_Unseen_Force_(3.5e_Prestige_Class)) that the DM has also approved.

I want my PC to be a monkey who hits hard and often, controls the battlefield with earth and air spells, flies at will, summons elementals, and—ultimately—changes gravity on the battlefield. I'd also like the character to be an expert with the quarterstaff.

- Is there a better arrangement of classes that suits my concept than what I've outlined above?
- What druid and monk alternative class features fit this concept? To be clear, although I know the druid's wild shape ability is awesome, I don't plan to use it because I'd rather my PC just be strong naturally.
- Is there a way to make a druid even more focused on casting earth and air spells?
- I want an awesome quarterstaff, but I'm a bit confused. Can a quarterstaff also be a magic staff? Can a druid even use a magic staff? Is there an air-themed or earth-themed magic staff that would suit my concept?
- I don't imagine the character using many magic items, but I don't know where to begin. What magic items mesh well with my concept?
  -I'm only committed to two feats: I plan to take the feat **Rashemi Elemental Summoning** (*Unapproachable East* 45) and the DM-approved homebrew feat [**Magically Aloft**](https://dnd-wiki.org/wiki/Magically_Aloft_(3.5e_Feat)). What other feats fit this earth-air-quarterstaff concept?

I don't really want to use more homebrew material as I'm already using quite a bit, but homebrew material is okay if it really fits. Also, I live in China, so anything Eastern flavored is preferred.

By the way, I'm not looking to make an overpowered character. I just want something fun that's still effective in combat. In case it matters, I think the campaign will center on locating a [*deck of many things*](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsICA.html#deck-of-many-things). (The DM has a copy that he's been wanting to use.)

Comment: There's so much to unpack here that I suspect you'll be told by more than just me to break this up into separate questions. First, though, is this: Are you using online homebrew stuff? If so, can this question link to those homebrew items? Also, as an aside, if your PC is "a monkey who hits hard and often, has battlefield control through earth and air spells, and can anytime fly around and summon elementals to supplement that control and then can start changing the gravity of the battlefield," then what do you expect the rest of the party to do? `:-)`

Comment: Yeah.  I thought about asking the questions separately, but imagined I would be given responses that  answered the question without fitting the build.  I was unsure if that would be better or if going very specific and detailed would be better to find fewer but more fitting answers.  Also, I imagine my character as a hard hitter, battlefield control... I will be quite weak in social situations, stealth, buffing, healing, planar situations, fighting against casters, fighting anything with spell resistance... I mean the list goes on... This character is more a specialist than a generalist IMO.

Comment: I forgot to mention.  As is, I will pump strength and wisdom, dump intelligence and charisma.

Comment: How about just starting with a [simple optimization question](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1641/8610) that, after laying out the campaign ground rules and what linking to the homebrew, asks, "What character and equipment choices should I make a druid even more focused on earth and air magic?* or something. To really help, though, the site needs the DM's build guidelines as detailed in that meta answer. It's not enough to tell the site what you want; the site also needs to know how much you have to spend.

Comment: Then, after getting some answers to that question, ask additional questions about issues that answers here haven't yet addressed.

Comment: Okay.  Noted.  I will reformat if this doesn't catch interest.  I'm very new here and have been asked to be much more specific so maybe swung the other way too hard.

Comment: It's totally cool. *Specific is preferred!* But imagine how long answers would have to be adequately address all three of the issues you raise. Also, what if an answer addresses 2 of the 3 issues really well but 1 terribly? How can people vote on such an answer so as to give you an idea of which one they think is best? And how will you know which *parts* are best? (I've found that when posing a question it's often wise to consider what kind of an answer I want, and how I would answer it were it posed to me.)

Comment: I took a shot at editing this. I hope that's okay. Feel free to rollback or edit further. You're still probably going to need to edit it further to fit the site's guidelines, though.

Comment: Re: *deck of many things*, should we assume this campaign [won’t go on for very long](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/57423/4563)?

Comment: For what it’s worth, I think this question is fine, and already have at least two suggestions for you, but votes to reopen have been stuck at 2 (of 5) for a while now, which suggests you’re going to have to edit this more. Separating straightforward mechanical questions could be a start—asking if a magic staff can be used as a quarterstaff would get an answer quickly, as would asking whether or not a druid can use one, but those should be two individual questions. Also, the community usually likes to see more explicit goals in optimization questions: damage, control, defense, etc.